# json web service datetime error

Tags: .net, json, web-services

I'm sending json data to a .net webservice but it throws an exception because CreatedDate":"/Date(1326289739524)/" can't be converted to a datetime object on the serverside.. any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm guessing it should be `DateTime(1326289739524)` instead of Date

Comment: Well if that's the case I have even more trouble because the script don't know the contents of the object. It received an object from the webservice, the contents is changed through a gui and it's all made with a dynamic interface between the html form and the object contents (id=>variable name mapping) but the date is never ever changed, so if json changes the objecttype by it's own I don't know how i'd ever fix it..

Comment: Unless I start iterating throuhg the objects and changing every date into a datetime equivalent but that feels a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to get the numeric portion extracted from the string then the rest is like this:

```
DateTime Temp = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

DateTime MyDateTime = Temp.AddMilliseconds(1326289739524);
```

Comment: Not possible since the exception is thrown before my webservice code starts running.

Comment: That is confusing.  In your question: "...can't be converted to a datetime object on the serverside"   Now you're saying the webservice code isn't running?  Where is the exception being thrown?  What is the text of the exception including the call stack?

Comment: We'll I'm using the classic asp.net webservice implementation so I don't really handle the code parsing the request, it just takes a object as a argument and before the method excecutes the exception is thrown. Anyway I managed to solve it by just intercepting the datetime objects on clientside and converting them to proper ones. To clarify I do not have code that converts json data to objects, asp.net does it for me. It expects a datetime but got data that couldn't be converted because of messy stuff happening in the clientside. (Partially beyond my control)